# Change bridge flags with libnl

Tags: c, linux, bridge, netlink

I'm trying to create bridge with libnl and change it's flags. Code:

```
#include <netlink/netlink.h>
#include <netlink/route/link.h>
#include <netlink/route/link/bridge.h>
#include <linux/if.h>

#define BRIDGE_NAME "brr"
int main()
{
    struct rtnl_link *link;
    struct rtnl_link *change;
    struct nl_sock *sk;

    int err;

    sk = nl_socket_alloc();
    if ((err = nl_connect(sk, NETLINK_ROUTE)) < 0) {
        nl_perror(err, "Unable to connect socket");
        return err;
    }

    link = rtnl_link_bridge_alloc();

    rtnl_link_set_name(link, BRIDGE_NAME);
    rtnl_link_set_family(link, AF_BRIDGE);
    rtnl_link_set_flags(link, IFF_UP);

    unsigned int flag = 0;

    if ((err = rtnl_link_add(sk, link, NLM_F_CREATE)) < 0)
    {
        nl_perror(err, "Unable to add link");
        return err;
    }

    rtnl_link_put(link);
    link = NULL;

    if (rtnl_link_get_kernel(sk, 0, BRIDGE_NAME, &link) < 0)
    {
        printf("can't get link\n");
        return -1;
    }


    change = rtnl_link_alloc();
    rtnl_link_unset_flags(change, IFF_UP);

    if ((err = rtnl_link_change(sk, link, change, 0)) < 0)
        printf("can't change flags: %s(%d)\n", nl_geterror(err), err);

    rtnl_link_put(link);
    rtnl_link_put(change);
    return 0;
}
```

How i compile:

```
gcc bridge-test.c -o createbr  $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libnl-3.0 libnl-genl-3.0 libnl-route-3.0)
```

And i get:

```
Operation not supported(-10)
```

It's not the libnl's error, it's returned from the kernel.

I'm on quite old Debian, but i don't think that this is the problem:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.144-3 (2019-02-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

libnl version:

```
$ aptitude versions libnl-3-dev
i   3.4.0-1
```

Problem occurs when i'm trying to remove IFF_UP flag. Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**CORRECT ANSWER**

This is bug in libnl-3.4.0 itself. Pay attention to this thread: http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/libnl/2017-November/thread.html#2384

It was already fixed https://github.com/thom311/libnl/commit/3c427d0f4fcca91a661d85d21cdea89d41271c6c

**OLD ANSWER, THIS IS WRONG ANSWER**

After day of googling(i've posted this question as act of despair) i think i've found the answer.

Create a bridge in linux:

```
$ sudo ip link add brr type bridge
```

Now look what iproute2 sends to the kernel when you are trying to put it down:

```
sudo strace -s 100 -f -o out -x ip link set brr down
```

```
...
1644  sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=32, type=RTM_NEWLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=1560223693, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=if_nametoindex("brr"), ifi_flags=0, ifi_change=0x1}}, iov_len=32}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
...
```

Now try to put down interface using code above. strace will give us:

```
...
1563  sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base={{len=32, type=RTM_SETLINK, flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_ACK, seq=0, pid=0}, {ifi_family=AF_BRIDGE, ifi_type=ARPHRD_NETROM, ifi_index=if_nametoindex("brr"), ifi_flags=IFF_BROADCAST|IFF_RUNNING|IFF_MULTICAST|IFF_LOWER_UP, ifi_change=0x1}}, iov_len=32}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 32
...
```

These two lines are almost the same with one exception:

```
iproute2:
ifi_family=AF_UNSPEC
mycode:
ifi_family=AF_BRIDGE
```

and request is handled by two different functions in the kernel:

```
rtnl_register(PF_UNSPEC, RTM_SETLINK, rtnl_setlink, NULL, 0);
...
rtnl_register(PF_BRIDGE, RTM_SETLINK, rtnl_bridge_setlink, NULL, 0);
```

Those lines are from `net/core/rtnetlink.c`

So, setting family to AF_UNSPEC for original link solves the problem. This isn't quite obvious, though.

UPDATE:
You cannot change bridge specific flags that way.